# Find all real eigenvalues, then find a basis for each eigenspace, and diagonalize, having problems when $\lambda =$ square root

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\4&5\end{bmatrix}$$
I found $$\lambda_1,\lambda_2 = \frac{7\pm \sqrt{57}}{2}$$

I'm having some technical difficulty finding the eigenvectors
which I believe to be in the $$ker(A-\lambda I_2)$$

or $$\begin{bmatrix}2-\frac{7\pm \sqrt{57}}{2}&3\\4&5-\frac{7\pm \sqrt{57}}{2}\end{bmatrix}=\vec 0$$
The solutions manual has different answers than mine and they skip through the last step in their computation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Lmgtfy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+of+[[2,3],[4,5]]).

Comment: @LaneFord: When you find the RREF of the plus eigenvalue, it is $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{1}{8} \left(3-\sqrt{57}\right) \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$. Are you able to get there?

Comment: I am not able to get there. I keep on ending up with a really complicated equation with a square root in the denominator.

Comment: @Moo finally able to get there I was having difficulty clearing the radical, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The kernel has to be nontrivial, so you can always conclude (without any calculations) that
\begin{align}
\ker(A-\lambda_{\pm}I)=\ker\begin{pmatrix}
2-\lambda_{\pm} & 3\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
With a short calculation, you get
\begin{align}
\ker\begin{pmatrix}
2-\lambda_{\pm} & 3\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\left\langle\ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{57}}{8} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle
\end{align}